# How to scale dataframe to bigger one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with following data:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | black |
| 2 | black |
| 3 | white |
| 4 | black |

My goal is to transform it like this:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | black |
| 1.5 | black |
| 2 | black |
| 2.5 | black |
| 3 | white |
| 3.5 | white |
| 4 | black |

My goal is to scale smaller dataframe accordingly by inserting points between them and filling values form second column to them. I would like also have a method to scaling it by using other mid point (it's always half space between points ex. when space between is 0.1 the  i want to put one point between them)

How I can acheive this ?

I was trying doing this by using some interoplation methods but can't move forward with them

Comment: What is a midpoint between `black` and `white`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Way:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.set_index('Col1')
df = df.reindex(np.arange(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + 0.5, 0.5)
           ).ffill().reset_index()
```

OUTPUT:

```
   Col1   Col2
0   1.0  black
1   1.5  black
2   2.0  black
3   2.5  black
4   3.0  white
5   3.5  white
6   4.0  black
```

Updated answer:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.set_index('Col1')
step_size = 0.1
df = df.reindex(np.arange(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + step_size, step_size)
           ).ffill().reset_index()
```

Comment: Yup. Manipulate the step size in `np.arrange`.